# How convert rows in a list using pandas

Tags: python, pandas

Used code and file: https://github.com/CaioEuzebio/Python-DataScience-MachineLearning/tree/master/SalesLogistics

I am working on an analysis using pandas. Basically I need to sort the orders by quantity of products, and containing the same products.

Example: I have order 1 and order 2, both have product A and product B. Using the product list and product quantity as a key I will create a pivot that will index this combination of products and return me the order who own the same products.

The general objective of the analysis is to obtain a dataframe as follows:

```
dfFinal 

listProds            Ordens  NumProds
[prod1,prod2,prod3]     1       3
                        2
                        3
[prod1,prod3,prod5]     7       3
                        15
                        25
[prod5]                 8       1
                        3
```

So far the code looks like this.

Setting the 'Order' column as index so that the first pivot is made.

```
df1.index=df1['Ordem']
df3 = df1.assign(col=df1.groupby(level=0).Produto.cumcount()).pivot(columns='col', values='Produto')
```

With this pivot I get the dataframe below.

```
df3 = 

col 0   1   2   3   4   5   6   7   8   9   ... 54  55  56  57  58  59  60  61  62  63
Ordem                                                                                   
10911KD YIZ12FF-A   YIZ12FF-A   YIIE2FF-A   YIR72FF-A   YIR72FF-A   YIR72FF-A   NaN NaN NaN NaN ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
124636  HYY32ZY-A   HYY32ZY-A   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
1719KD5 YI742FF-A   YI742FF-A   YI742FF-A   YI742FF-A   NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
22215KD YI762FF-A   YI762FF-A   YI762FF-A   YI762FF-A   YI762FF-A   YI762FF-A   YI6E2FF-A   YI6E2FF-A   YI6E2FF-A   NaN ... NaN NaN NaN NaN NaN
```

When I finish running the code, NaN values ​​appear, and I need to remove them from the lines so that I don't influence the analysis I'm doing.

Comment: this way? ```df3.assign(ordem=df3['var1'].str.split(',')).explode('listprod')```

Comment: I tryed this way and it returns a error. ```KeyError: 'Var1'```

Comment: sorry typo `df.assign(ordem=df['listprod'].str.split(',')).explode('listprod')`